# which python IDE is close to R for running a line code after the whole file

Tags: python, ide

I switched from R to python. I can not find any proper IDE that can run a single run after running the whole file. Spyder seems promissing but the text editor is terrible. Atom is good but everytime I have to run whole .py file. here is exact my problme:
I run machine learning and load data through .py file and after that I want to performed some test without running again my file; just need to write on python shell. Which python IDE can provide this single practicality?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any special IDE to do this. Just launch your python program with the -i option. If you are looking for an IDE that makes it easy to do this (although you don't need an IDE to do it) in PyCharm you can just click on tab and be at the terminal where you can run this command.

Example code:

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5,7]
someString = "hello this is a string"

def some_function(a, b):
    return a+b
```

Launching the program: (type this into terminal / cmd prompt / etc)

```
python -i test.py
```

Checking variables, using functions, etc etc (all after the execution is done)

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\2\pyprojects>python -i test.py
>>> someList
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
>>> someString
'hello this is a string'
>>> some_function(1,2)
3
```